# Using psr-4 namespaces fails

Tags: php, rest, namespaces

I have a problem with using psr-4 namespaces. The structure of my application is a bit complicated but I try to explain. If something is not clear, please feel free to ask!

First of all I have two folders on the same level. One with backoffice classes and the other one with a rest api implementation.

```
/myapp/backoffice/
/myapp/rest/
```

Two example classes in the backoffice folder look like this:

```
// File: /myapp/backoffice/src/Services/Abstract.php
<?php
namespace Myapp\Backoffice\Services;

abstract class AbstractService
{
}
```

and

```
// File: /myapp/backoffice/src/Services/Login.php
<?php
namespace Myapp\Backoffice\Services;

class LoginService extends AbstractService
{
}
```

The composer.json under /myapp/backoffice/ contains this declaration:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Myapp\\Backoffice\\": "src/"
  }
},
```

In one of my rest resources I want to call the login service from the backoffice. The file looks like this:

```
<?php
// File: /myapp/rest/MyModule/src/Resource/LoginResource.php
namespace Myapp\MyModule\Resource;

use Myapp\Backoffice\Services\LoginService;
use ZF\Rest\AbstractResourceListener;

class LoginResource extends AbstractResourceListener
{
    public function fetchAll($params = [])
    {
        $service = new LoginService($params);
        ...
    }
}
```

The composer.json under /myapp/rest/ contains this declaration:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Myapp\\MyModule\\": "MyModule/src/",
    "Myapp\\Backoffice\\": "../backoffice/src/"
  }
},
```

Then I call the rest api and get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Myapp\\Backoffice\\Services\\LoginService' not found in /myapp/rest/MyModule/src/Resource/LoginResource.php on line 12
```

It's the line with the constructor which fails.

And here are the autoload's:

```
// File: /myapp/backoffice/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
return array(
    'Myapp\\Backoffice\\' => array($baseDir . '/src')
);

// File: /myapp/rest/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
return array(
    'Myapp\\MyModule\\' => array($baseDir . '/MyModule/src'),
    'Myapp\\Backoffice\\' => array($baseDir . '/../backoffice/src')
);
```

Comment: have you tried `composer dumpautoload`? Also can you post the contents of `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` for both directories?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your filename is `Login.php` but your class name is `LoginService` which is not PSR-4 compatible. The filename must match the class name, so rename the file to `LoginService.php` and it should work.

The same is true for `AbstractService` and `Abstract.php` which should be renamed to `AbstractService.php`